# Scrapy: Connection to the other side was lost

Tags: scrapy

I am having this problem. I am using nord VPN as a proxy and scrapy to crawl a site.
But when I add USER-AGENT it gives me connection lost error.
Without USER AGENT site takes me to captcha which could be bypassed by adding USER AGENT but by adding user agent it is giving me connection lost error.

Comment: Hello, need more information such as site url, your attempt at solving issue, etc.

Comment: Well That Has Been Resolved. I Don't know what the actual issue was, but changing the Ip to a specific server worked and only works on that IP, not on others.